# How to get the time elapsed time after using the reset of the "Elapsed Time" component?

Tags: labview, daq-mx

I am calculating the capacitance of a circuit using LabVieW. I have tried to get the time after the voltage across it reaches 2.5V. I am giving a supply of 5V. I used a logic operator and connected it to the reset to the elapsed time component. But I get zero as the time gets reseted. I want to get the actual time elapsed.

**The block diagram of the circuit:**

[image: The block diagram of the circuit]

Comment: I believe Elapsed Time is meant to be used more like a timer than a stopwatch--the focus being on comparing a timing constant to a running timer and letting you know when they match. Instead consider getting a timestamp at the start and another timestamp when the voltage reaches 2.5V, then get the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code: Do not wire something on the reset and place a False on the Auto Reset Input

Block Diagram
[image]